# Upgraded to 14.10, brightness control quit working - Intel HD 4400

Tags: intel-graphics, acer, 14.10

After upgrading, I can no longer control the brightness of my monitor with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>⇐</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>⇒</kbd>.

I followed the instructions here - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144815 - but it still isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried adding the kernel parameter acpi_backlight=vendor from the GRUB screen?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Restart your machine. When you get the Ubuntu boot menu (usually a black screen with some Ubuntu options), press e. Then add acpi_backlight=vendor before the quiet parameter:
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash

Comment: What computer make and model were you using? (for future reference)

Comment: @smile4ever: why 'before quiet parameter'?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and write:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Type in your password, then copy-paste the following text into gedit:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

and save again!

Comment: Yes it solved my problem...Thx

Comment: Can confirm that this is a working solution for Toshiba Protege Z830 running 14.10 Utopic. Thank you Sir, and plus 1 to you both.

Comment: This did not solve the problem on my Samsung. I tried both the xorg.conf.d and the Grub approach too. Neither worked.

Comment: My brightness keys only alter brightness between seemingly 2 levels: bright and slightly brighter. This did not improve for my  ASUS TX201.