# Low brightness Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, brightness, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I have an Asus F550LNV-DM092H with NVIDIA 840m + Intel HD 4400 but since i've installed ubuntu 14.10 the brightness is too low although in the system settings is at maximum.
Some help?

Comment: Have you checked Bios settings?

Comment: there is no options for brightness settings in Bios

Answer (score 0):

If you already set it in the system settings to the highest level you may change it on the monitor (or laptop configuration)?

Comment: how ? Yes it's a laptop

Comment: If you don't know how it's possible I'd like to refer to a handbook or an user manual, but the Asus page doesn't say anything neither. http://www.asus.com/Search/?SearchKey=F550LNV ... I only know that usually it's possible to alter the brightness of a laptop display.

Comment: in italy it's f550lnv but x550lnv in other countries. http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X550LNV/ ok thank you

Comment: Ah, therefore I was directed firstly to this model. I didn't know. Okay, if you have the manual open - http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X550LA/E_eManual_X550LA_LB_LC_VER7926.pdf - you search for "brightness" and find: Increase brightness: Fn + F6. Give me review and I will post the solution as answer and you can mark it that way.

Comment: Yes i already tried fn + f6 but it doesn't work. Actually nothing happens

Comment: Do you have it power-plugged in? Then it may be damaged. You can try it with a different OS (some live distributions or Windows *eg*) to see if it works.

Comment: Yes i have, and it works. On windows 8.1 fn + f6 works good.

Comment: Ok, if it really does then the Fn key (or the configuration) may be configured wrong in Ubuntu. Do other Fn-combinations work in your Ubuntu? Also have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/541525/upgraded-to-14-10-brightness-control-quit-working-intel-hd-4400?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/552507/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fn-brightness-key-stopped-working?rq=1

Comment: I've already seen those post, but the both doesn't work for me :( 
Yes all the others Fn-combinations works on ubuntu, it's just fn+f5 and fn+f6 which regulate the brightness

Comment: Ok, you should add this information to your original question if you can. I don't know anything more you could try, sorry and good luck!